# How to get the array object from a specific history.location.pathname

Tags: reactjs, location, history, pathname

My issue is that when i call the function getAllFlashCardsFromQuest(), its call all flash cards ever created in all the pages, i wanna only the objects that comes from a specific pathname, or a way to filter the cards array.

```
async function getCards() {
    let cardsValues = await getAllFlashCardsFromQuest() as FlashCard[]
    let cardsFiltered = cardsValues.filter(()=>{
        return history.location.pathname === 'CriarAlternativaQuest'
    })
    console.log(cardsFiltered)
    setCards(cardsFiltered)
}
```

the object look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's not much context with your code, so I can only help so much, but one thing's for sure, and that is `history.location.pathname` isn't changing and you're comparing it with another constant. So `cardsFiltered` will be either a list of **true** or a list of **false**.

Whenever you're filtering a list, you need to take each item or a property of each item and use that in your comparison.

Ex.

```
async function getCards() {
    let cardsValues = await getAllFlashCardsFromQuest() as FlashCard[]
    let cardsFiltered = cardsValues.filter((cardValueItem) => {
        return cardValueItem.pathname === 'CriarAlternativaQuest'
    })
}
```

The thing is that you need to figure out what value or property inside of your `cardsValues` list that you need to compare it with '*CriarAlternativaQuest*'

Comment: I know, but there is no other property that differs from the cardsValues that i can compare, because the object is the same, i want to filter by the origin of the object.